# Adjusting start and end dates sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, comparison

I have the below data for one id with the start and end dates and their cost

```
ID    Start Date    End date    Cost
121   06/06/2016    17/09/2017  157.5
121   21/08/2016    16/10/2016  247.5
121   20/08/2017    17/09/2017  450
```

The output should be like this

```
ID    Start Date    End date      Cost
121   06/06/2016    20/08/2016    157.5
121   21/08/2016    16/10/2016    247.5
121   17/10/2016    19/08/2017    157.5
121   20/08/2017    17/09/2017    450
```

where the previous record should end based on the next record and show relevant amounts. Can someone please help on how to achieve this in SQL 2008. Thank you.

Comment: SQL 2008 makes me suspect this is a sql server question.Please change the tag if that is the case.

Comment: ...and after fixing your tags, please tell us what the logic is here.

Comment: Hi, this is sql server question.  Can someone advice on how to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 1):

These sorts of time-overlap problems are challenging -- and all the more so without `lead()` and `lag()`.

The idea is to get information for each date, and the bring it back together.  Along the way, we need to keep track of the "in"s and "out"s for the different prices.  In SQL Server 2008, this makes liberal use of `apply`.

This query solves your problem:

```
with t as (
      select id, cast(sdate as date) as sdate, cast(edate as date) edate, cost
      from (values (121, '2016-06-06', '2017-09-17', 157.5),
                   (121, '2016-08-21', '2016-10-16', 247.5),
                   (121, '2017-08-20', '2017-09-17', 450)
           ) v(id, sdate, edate, cost)
     ),
     dates as (
      select id, dte, cost, sum(inc) as inc
      from ((select id, sdate as dte, cost, 1 as inc
             from t
            ) union all
            (select id, dateadd(day, 1, edate), NULL, -1 as inc
             from t
            )
           ) d
      group by id, dte, cost
     ),
     d as (
      select dates.*, d.suminc
      from dates outer apply
           (select sum(d.inc) as suminc
            from dates d
            where d.id = dates.id and d.dte <= dates.dte
           ) d
     )
select d.id, d.dte as start_date,
       dateadd(day, -1, dnext.dte) as end_dte,
       coalesce(d.cost, dprev.cost) as cost
from d cross apply
     (select top (1) dnext.*
      from d dnext
      where dnext.id = d.id and dnext.dte > d.dte
      order by dnext.dte
     ) dnext outer apply
     (select top (1) dprev.*
      from d dprev
      where dprev.id = d.id and dprev.dte < d.dte and dprev.suminc = d.suminc
      order by dprev.dte desc
     ) dprev
order by d.dte;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/MCFMM4407) is a rextester.

Comment: Many thanks Gordon for your prompt answer. That really worked like a charm. Can't thank enough for providing the solution. You have made my day. Really grateful for the people here who are taking out of their time and helping people like me. You are real stars.